# Picture and text on video capture

Tags: c++, opencv

I would like to put an image on video and i'm wondering if it's possible in opencv without multithreading. 
I would like to avoid it because in my project i am operating on RPI 0W(that's whyi don't want multithreading) .
i can't find anything about it on internet. I got some basic code in c++ . I'm new to open cv.

```
      int main(){
VideoCapture cap(0);
if (!cap.isOpened())
{
    cout << "error"<<endl;
    return -1;
}
Mat edges;
namedWindow("edges", 1);
Mat img = imread("logo.png");
   for (;;)
{
    Mat frame;
    cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
    imshow("edges", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
        imshow("edges", img);
    imshow("edges", frame);
    if (waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you try to explain in more detail what you have already attempted?

Comment: I tried load an image on another Mat variable and show it in the same frame(imshow("the same name",image)) 
but in loop it woas showing ones a video capture once an image. thats why i'm talking about multithreading

Comment: By "show it in the same frame", do you mean side by side or one upon another?

Comment: yes i meant exactly that

Answer (score 1):

In OpenCV showing two things in the same window overwrites the previous one which I think is happening in your case.
You can use OpenCV addWeighted() function or bitwise operations.
OpenCV has good documentation on this. You can find it [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/dc4/tutorial_adding_images.html)